# How to match dictionary key to string and put into new dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary: dict

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'network3_ICU_0001_01_(0, 1)': [(0.39, 'yes')], network3_ICU_0001_01_(0, 2)': [(0.79, 'yes'), 'network3_ICU_0001_01_(1, 2)': [(0.39, 'yes')]]}
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'network3_MCU_0032_02_(0, 1)': [(0.47, 'yes')], 'network3_MCU_0032_02_(0, 2)': [(0.55, 'yes')], 'network3_MCU_0032_02_(1, 2)': [(0.39, 'yes')]}
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'network3_CCA_0045_03_(0, 1)': [(0.43, 'no')], 'network3_CCA_0045_03_(0, 2)': [(0.53, 'no')], 'network3_CCA_0045_03_(1, 2)': [(0.99, 'no')]}
```

I want to extract the sub key values that contain (0,1) at the end so the result looks like this:

```
{'network3_ICU_0001_01_(0, 1)': [(0.39, 'yes')]}
{'network3_MCU_0032_02_(0, 1)': [(0.47, 'yes')]}
{'network3_CCA_0045_03_(0, 1)': [(0.43, 'no')]}
```

and then I want to move it into a new dictionary

The code I have so far is the following:

```
return_values = {k:v for k,v in network3.items() if k.endswith('(0, 1)')}
print(return_values)
```

This code doesn't return any vaulues and I'm thinking it's probably because I'm calling the key instead of the subkey... I'm not sure how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: There's a few non-closed quotes and missing bracket in your example dictionary - could this be effecting the results?  Otherwise the code works for me.

Comment: Ah, my bad it does work! You're right it was just the non-closed quotes.  But I was wondering how I can move the results into a new dictionary? @Kingsley

Comment: `return_values` is a new dictionary.

Comment: @Kingsley Only problem here is that when I use my code, the dictionary that is created:  `return_values` separates each of my keys within the dictionary line by line instead of being separated by comas (which is the standard for dictionaries).  Any idea how I can go about this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of this in the question. It's not clear to me what the problem is.  A dictionary is a dictionary, so this must part of the content, or the output formatting.

Comment: I think I see the problem.. I have dict as:  `dict = defaultdict(list)`.  Not sure how to change it to an actual dictionary.  The reason I set dict to default dic in the first place was because I wanted to merge two dictionaries together.. and I couldn't unless I did this.                                                                    @Kingsley